# Fisher's test of periodicity

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I have evenly sampled time series on which I applied Fourier transform. I am trying do determine if the signal contains statistically significant periodic components. I have succeeded with determining period. Now I am trying to calculate p-value for this component using these formulas derived by Fisher:

\begin{align}
I(\lambda) &= \frac{1}{2\pi n}\bigg|\sum_{t=1}^n X_te^{-it\lambda}\bigg|^2  \\[5pt]
Y_r &= \frac{I(\lambda_r)}{\sum_{j=1}^mI(\lambda_j)}, \qquad r = 1, \ldots, m,  \\[5pt]
P(Y>y) &= 1- \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j{m\choose j}(1-jy)_+^{m-1}
\end{align}

The first formula is just squared discrete Fourier transfom.

$n$ - length of time data series
$m = (n - 1) / 2$ is number of AC harmonic components without Nyquist frequency

The problem I am solving is that for some values of $g$-statistics (denoted as $Y_r$ in this example) the sum of series is diverging. Let's take an example:
\begin{align}
n &= 287  \\
m &= 143  \\
y &= 0.0044598585072423936
\end{align}
Partial sum for $j = 1$ is:
$$
(-1)^1 + 143C1 \times (1 - 0.0044598585072423936)^142 = -75.802
$$
The meaning of P value is probability which should be number between 0 (the event never occurs) and 1 (the event occurs always). Adding next terms to the sum just make the resulting value larger in absolute value. Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you double check your last equation `(-1)^1 + 143C1 * (1 - 0.0044598585072423936)^142 = -75.802`?

Comment: I checked it, it should be OK. What is unclear when should "+" operator apply - before calculating exponential function or after. But in principle the problem remains. For small values of g-statistics the value between parentheses is too close to 1. The combination term before parentheses is growing faster than the value of third term is approaching zero. This is the source of instability.

Comment: What is your C1?

Comment: Shortcut for binomial coefficient 143!/(1! * (143-1)!)).

Comment: Oh okay. Alright. Maybe edit the $143C_1$ to just $143$.